# Do I have to upload the same app twice to Firebase for iOS?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, dart

I recently created an Android app and connected it to Firebase. I obviously selected the Android option when connecting. The question now is: Do I have to upload the same app to Firebase again but this time selecting iOS in order to build for iOS?

Comment: Ah yep, because firebase will generate a .plist file for iOS app and you will use plist file in your iOS project (it includes API keys…)

Comment: To clarify, you do not need to upload the app to firebase. You need to create separate app registrations for Android and iOS. If you want to make full use of Crashlytics then you do need to upload the relevant symbols for each app

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create separate apps for android and iOS under the same firebase project. Each will have its own configuration file that needs to be added to the relevant project codebase. This does not mean that the resources consumed for each app is different. The apps will still be using the same instance of Firestore, RTDB and the rest of the cool stuff.

These will give you details about configuring each app. [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) & [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)